# breaking lines in listings environment

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I am trying to make listing environment brake lines. Unfortunately `breaklines=true` does not work for me. Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=matlab,breaklines=true, extendedchars=true, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt, basicstyle=\footnotesize, frame=lines, keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue}, commentstyle=\color{green!50!black}}

\lstset{emph={classdef, properties, methods},emphstyle={\color{blue}\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algorytm}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Funkcja \emph{createFoR} klasy \emph{row}., label=func_createFoR, float=ht]
classdef row < handle

properties
rp  %promien rownoleznika
end

methods 
    function [T1 T2] = createFoR(obj,hT,Alpha,Beta,DeltaAlpha,DeltaBeta)
         P1(1,1) = obj.r * cosd(Beta);
         P1(1,2) = obj.r * cosd(90 - Beta);
         P1(1,3) = obj.r * tand(90 - (Alpha + DeltaAlpha));
         P1(2,:) = hT.P(1,:);
         %hT - trojkat z wyzszego wiersza
         P1(3,1) = obj.r * cosd(Beta + DeltaBeta);
         P1(3,2) = obj.r * cosd(90 - (Beta + DeltaBeta));
         P1(3,3) = obj.r * tand(90 - (Alpha + DeltaAlpha)); 
         T1 = triangle(P1);
         P2(1,:) = hT.P(1,:);
         P2(2,:) = hT.P(3,:);
         P2(3,:) = P1(3,:);
         T2 = triangle(P2);
    end
end
\end{lstlisting}
```

This is how it looks: [image: http://i.imgur.com/VjTH3ku.png]

May I kindly ask you for help?

Comment: `breaklines` does work for me in lines 8, 15, and 16, if the code starts with `\documentclass[a5paper]{article}\usepackage{xcolor}`.

Comment: BTW, `\lstset{columns=flexible}` makes the lines shorter and the spacing of the words more natural.

Comment: Thank you Heiko. However I am using mwrep class which defines style for documents written in polish and breaklines does not work with it. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `mwrep` sets `\exhyphenpenalty=10000`. This setting prevents line breakings after explicit hyphens or `\discretionary` items. The latter uses package `listings`.

The following patch resets the setting for `\exhyphenpenalty` for listings:

```
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{\exhyphenpenalty=50\relax}
\makeatother
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{\exhyphenpenalty=50\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=matlab,breaklines=true, extendedchars=true, numbers=left, numb

\lstset{emph={classdef, properties, methods},emphstyle={\color{blue}\bfseries}}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algorytm}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Funkcja \emph{createFoR} klasy \emph{row}., label=fu
classdef row < handle

properties
rp  %promien rownoleznika
end

methods
    function [T1 T2] = createFoR(obj,hT,Alpha,Beta,DeltaAlpha,DeltaBeta)
         P1(1,1) = obj.r * cosd(Beta);
         P1(1,2) = obj.r * cosd(90 - Beta);
         P1(1,3) = obj.r * tand(90 - (Alpha + DeltaAlpha));
         P1(2,:) = hT.P(1,:);
         %hT - trojkat z wyzszego wiersza
         P1(3,1) = obj.r * cosd(Beta + DeltaBeta);
         P1(3,2) = obj.r * cosd(90 - (Beta + DeltaBeta));
         P1(3,3) = obj.r * tand(90 - (Alpha + DeltaAlpha));
         T1 = triangle(P1);
         P2(1,:) = hT.P(1,:);
         P2(2,:) = hT.P(3,:);
         P2(3,:) = P1(3,:);
         T2 = triangle(P2);
    end
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

---

If possible, I would use `columns=flexible`, it weakens the vertical alignment a little, thus it depends on the source code formatting, if this is an option.
But the benefit are smaller line width, because package `listings` do not need to reserve space for the wider characters of the font. It reduces line breaks and the words of the listings are set in a more natural way and are easier to read.

For comparison, the next image is generated with the following setting:

```
\lstset{columns=flexible}
```

> [image: Result with columns=flexible]